# Using Rails 5.1 to send compiled webpacker asset as response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Thank you in advance.

I am trying to have my Rails 5.1 app respond to an "application/javascript" request.

In essence, I want to be able to put a  tag with a src pointing to my Rails app so that I can request a JS file to be executed.

I have under app/javascript/packs a file that only has `console.log( 'hello_world' )` for now. All I want to do, is have that execute on my intended page.

I have a controller action that is as follows:

```
def hello_world_js
  send_file(
    "#{Rails.root}/app/public/packs/hello_world.js",
    :filename => "hello_world.js",
    :type => "application/javascript"
  )
end
```

The src request leads to this controller action. I, however, get the following error:

`ActionController::MissingFile (Cannot read file /Users/mac/Workspace/rails_app_dir/app/public/packs/hello_world.js)`

This makes sense to me.

Normally, you would have a `javascript_pack_tag` in a view file that will trigger the compile and return of the javascript src. However, I'm not going through those motions, so I don't have a compiled JS file ready.

How can I set it up, so that this can be triggered from a `<script/>` src request?

Projecting into the future, I imagine the compiled file will have a string of characters after it's name. `hello_world.js` will actually be something like `hello_world-8f87b73be32a9b3e4fb2.js` - how can I accommodate this too?

One solution that comes to mind is to use the endpoint to render a .js.erb file that then appends the tag again. I want to avoid this because then I'm making two requests to my server.

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by looking at the Webpacker source code.

I can find the public file as well as trigger compilation in dev form the controller via:

`Webpacker.manifest.lookup!( 'hello_world.js' )`

Webpacker::Manifest can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/105c9e8d11a70b8f6f5f7d5232537665599bfc4a/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb).

Really, I found this by looking for the definition of `javascript_pack_tag`.

Hope this is useful to the wayfarer and if it is drop a line because I'd love to chat about this.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question!